Need a function to complete before running next function swift
I need to run a function A, have function A complete before running function B, have function B complete before function C starts and my the await statements are not working and functions are running at the same time.  I have separate Alamofire requests inside function A and function B
@State var a = [A]()
@State var b = [B]()
@State var cDict = [[String:Any]]()

func runAlgorithm() {
        Task {
            await functionA()
            await functionB()
            await functionC()
         }
}

func functionA() async {
...code...
 a = ...
}

func functionB() async {
...code...
 b = ...
}

func functionC() async {
...code...
  create dictionary cDict from a and b
}
          


You need to turn the Alamofire requests into async/await too. You did not show the calls to those methods, but my guess is, you haven't done that.

I believe this code will execute serially since there is no async let here, can you provide more code with each function?

@matt makes sense thanks!

There isn’t enough information to provide a solution so you need to add more details.

@matt was correct needed put the alamofire requests into async/await as well

Per Matt’s suggestion I needed to turn the Alamofire requests into async/await too
